# Python google search not returning expected output

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-search

I'm trying to do a google search using python, it's basically web scraping. I'm searching using a specific phrase, and I'm expecting a detailed output. I also would like to avoid using other web scraping modules, such as `bs4` (BeautifulSoup4) or `urllib`.

I'm using the `googlesearch-python` module, but it's not working as expected:

```
from googlesearch import search

search("my search", advanced=True)
```

but I get this output:

<generator object search at 0x000001B4F198F290>

and when I try using the print() function:

```
from googlesearch import search

print(search("my search", advanced=True))
```

it still returns:

<generator object search at 0x000001B4F198F290>.

(Advanced is an argument that makes the search more detailed and return more information.)

Sometimes, I also get no output at all (meaning that the program ends immediately, as if there were 0 lines of code in it), and other times I get the generator object output. Is there a way to return a clean, detailed output with the `googlesearch-python` module? (This question is a follow up to my previous question about the `googlesearch` module: "Python google search 'advanced' argument unexpected")

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch/issues/21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a Python generator. Try to convert it into a List to see the actual results.

```
from googlesearch import search

# Convert the generator to a list and print the results
results = list(search("my search", num=10, advanced=True))
print(results)
```